# Does ryanair allow an extra bag if bought at the airport shops?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage, ryanair

Ryanair luggage policy has recently changed.
Before I could take two bags, so if I bought something at the airport I would just put it in my luggage.
Since I am now only carrying a small backpack I would like to know if they allow stuff bought at the airport as a second bag.

I've seen it before (some time ago) stated in some shops that this would be allowed. I am not sure if that applies to all airports/shops though and if the recent policy change didn't change that aspect as well.

**Does ryanair allow an extra bag if bought at the airport shops?**

Note: By extra bag I don't mean travel luggage/trolley bought at the airport but just a plastic bag with bottles, tshirst, etc or something equivalent. Not necessarily bought at the duty free.

Comment: if "something equivalent" is liquids and similar duty free purchases, you already have an answer. If it's magazines and tshirts and whatnot from random shops, I doubt very much it would be allowed.

Comment: @KateGregory what do you mean "random shops"? shops outside the airport?

Comment: No, just regular airport shops that are not [duty free selling liquids and other restricted items]. The majority of shops in most airports are not duty free.

Comment: @KateGregory I don't think this is a duplicate. As the asker says, Ryanair's policy has changed recently (as in, in the last couple of weeks). That question is five years old.

Comment: @KateGregory I mean in an shop, not only in duty free.

Comment: @DavidRicherby normally we don't allow duplicates just because the original question is old. You can always edit the original question, add a bounty or add a new answer to it.

Comment: @KateGregory Actually, it is allowed to carry on an extra bag of random purchases. This was the result of an argument between Ryanair (who wanted to reduce carry on luggage) and the airports they serve (who want passengers to buy things). As the dupe says, it depends on whether the departure airport has this kind of agreement with Ryanair.

Comment: @JonathanReez This policy serves everybody badly. If the question hadn't been asked before, nobody would have to give up rep to encourage a good answer; they'd just post the question and wait. And adding new answers to old questions works very badly because the new answer never gets any attention and the accepted answer remains out of date.

Comment: @DavidRicherby please open a Meta discussion about this.